# Cron Job in play framework

Tags: java, asynchronous, playframework, cron, playframework-1.x

I'm trying to create web service using Play Framework and I want to join it with [scheduling](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.3/jobs#scheduling), every minute will call the `getRunJob()`.

It works when call directly to `http://localhost:9000/run`, but when I tried to call from my `Scheduler` class using `WS.WSRequest resp = WS.url("localhost:9000/run");` it become error `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal URL: localhost://null`.

Is it anything wrong with my code? Please advice, thank you...

**Application.java**

```
public class Application extends Controller {

    public static void index() {
        render();
    }

    public static void getRunJob() {
        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:MM");
        renderText("Running... " + format.format(new Date()));
    }

}
```

**Scheduler.java**

```
@On("1 * * * * ?")
public class Scheduler extends Job {

    @Override
    public void doJob() {
        System.out.println("Test");
        WS.WSRequest resp = WS.url("localhost:9000/run");
        System.out.println(resp.get().getString());
    }
}
```

**routes**

```
GET     /                                       Application.index
GET     /run                                    Application.getRunJob
```

Comment: Do you need the protocol in the URL?

Comment: I need to run the `getRunJob` based on `routes` file. I tried before calling another web service but created using python and it works just using `WS.url(String url)`, but when trying to access my own web service it got error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the protocol to WS.url:

```
WS.WSRequest resp = WS.url("http://localhost:9000/run");
```